# Perfect List Structure?

Tags: data-structures

Is it theoretically possible to have a data-structure that has

O(1) access, insertion, deletion times

and dynamic length?

I'm guessing one hasn't yet been invented or we would entirely forego the use of arrays and linked lists (seperately) and instead opt to use one of these.

Is there a proof this cannot happen, and therefore some relationship between access-time, insertion-time and deletion-time (like conservation of energy) that suggests if one of the times becomes constant the other has to be linear or something along that.

Comment: Do you, for some reason, want to restrict yourself to lists?  If so, you should clarify your question.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the order? I'm assuming since you're saying list then yes, but just checking...

Comment: yea I did need to preserve order.

Comment: @PHS i wasn't particularly after lists, arrays also work, just the idea of a block of memory that preserves order as J Trana said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's enumerate your requirements instead of mentioning a single possible data structure first.

Basically, you want constant operation time for...

- **Access**

  - If you know exactly where the entity that you're looking for is, this is easily accomplished.  A hashed value or an indexed location is something that can be used to uniquely identify entities, and provide constant access time.  **The chief drawback** with this approach is that you will not be able to have truly identical entities placed into the same data structure.
- **Insertion**

  - If you can insert at the very end of a list without having to traverse it, then you can accomplish constant access time. **The chief drawback** with this approach is that you have to have a reference pointing to the end of your list at all times, which must be modified at update time (which, in theory, should be a constant time operation as well). If you decide to hash every value for fast access later, then there's a cost for both calculating the hash and adding it to some backing structure for quick indexing.
- **Deletion Time**

  - The main principle here is that there can't be too many moving parts; I'm deleting from a fixed, well-defined location.  Something like a `Stack`, `Queue`, or `Deque` can provide that *for the most part*, in that they're deleting only one element, either in LIFO or FIFO order.  **The chief drawback** with this approach is that you can't scan the collection to find any elements in it, since that would take O(n) time.  If you were going about the route of using a hash, you could *probably* do it in O(1) time at the cost of some multiple of O(n) storage space (for the hashes).
- **Dynamic Length**

  - If you're chaining references, then that shouldn't be such a big deal; `LinkedList` already has an internal `Node` class.  **The chief drawback** to this approach is that your memory is not infinite.  If you were going the approach of hashes, then the more stuff you have to hash, the higher of a probability of a collision (which does take you out of the O(1) time, and put you more into an amortized O(1) time).

By this, there's really no single, perfect data structure that gives you absolutely constant runtime performance with dynamic length.  I'm also unsure of any value that would be provided by writing a proof for such a thing, since the general use of data structures is to make use of its positives and live with its negatives (in the case of hashed collections:  love the access time, no duplicates is an ouchie).

Although, if you were willing to live with some amortized performance, a set is likely your best option.

Comment: I'm just curious from a mathematical viewpoint (it seems a proof may be possible given the explanation you provided) since if there's no reason to believe its impossible the it may be worthwhile to pursue the creation of such a thing (ex: Brodal Que which offers extreme performance for a heap structure, but is only useful for extremely large volumes of data) Perhaps such a structural analogue for lists (i'm hoping) can be given rise to

Answer (score 3):

No such data structure exists on current architectures.

Informal reasoning:

- To get better than `O(n)` time for insertion/deletion, you need a tree data structure of some sort
- To get `O(1)` random access, you can't afford to traverse a tree

The best you can do is get `O(log n)` for all these operations. That's a fairly good compromise, and there are plenty of data structures that achieve this (e.g. a [Skip List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)).

You can also get "close to `O(1)`" by using trees with high branching factors. For example, Clojure's persistent data structure use 32-way trees, which gives you `O(log32 n)` operations. For practical purposes, that's fairly close to `O(1)` (i.e. for realistic sizes of `n` that you are likely to encounter in real-world collections)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to settle for amortized constant time, it is called a hash table.

Comment: Hash tables don't support O(1) insertion / deletion at arbitrary list positions....

Comment: Who said anything about list positions?  He wanted constant time probe, insertion and deletion.  Hash tables give exactly that.  If desired, integers can be used as the hash keys (this is, for example, how PHP arrays work.)

Comment: Question is about a "List Structure". Insertion in a list implies re-numbering all following elements. Hash tables can't do that in O(1) time.

Answer (score 1):

The closest such datastructure is a B+-tree, which can easily answer questions like "what is the `k`th item", but performs the requisite operations in `O(log(n))` time. Notably iteration (and access of close elements), especially with a cursor implementation, can be very close to array speeds.

- Throw in an extra factor, `C`, as our "block size" (which should be a multiple of a cache line), and we can get something like insertion time ~ `log_C(n) + log_2(C) + C`. For `C = 256` and 32-bit integers, `log_C(n) = 3` implies our structure is 64GB. Beyond this point you're probably looking for a hybrid datastructure and are more worried about network cache effects than local ones.